# How to locate duplicate JS elements BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

html =

```
<span class="title">
    <a href="VIDEO HREF" title="title" class="js-pop">title text</a>"
</span>
```

Code =

```
class Client(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for link in soup.findAll('a', class_='js-pop'):
    href = link.get('href')
    print(href)
    print(link.text)
```

I want it to return the href link and the title text.

When I run it prints every class that has the text "js-pop" in it and there are multiple classes named "js-pop" that aren't classes I want to scrape.

I've attempted scraping the page in selenium and it prints "none" when I try to locate the href on class='js-pop'

the elements I'm trying to scrape all have unique ID's, CSS selectors, and xpaths

How should I go about locating this element?

Comment: Are you sure `source` contains the original HTML? Try adding `print(source)` and checking it.

Comment: Just checked it and it does.

Comment: if I could locate the span class and search everything in that specific span I might be able to locate it. I'm unsure how to do this though.

Comment: Can you give the URL? We could then see all the HTML.

Comment: It's an adult website. I don't know if I'm aloud to post it.

Comment: Probably best not. You could though [edit] the question to include a representative sample of the HTML, and what your expected output for it should be.

Comment: I updated it to show the span and what I want my return values to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the `href`, the `title` and the span text, you could do the following:

```
import bs4 as bs

html = '<span class="title"><a href="VIDEO HREF" title="title" class="js-pop">title text</a></span>'
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for link in soup.findAll('a', class_='js-pop', href=True, title=True):
    print(link['href'])
    print(link['title'])
    print(link.text)
```

This would display:

```
VIDEO HREF
title
title text
```

By adding `href=True` and `title=True`, it tells the find to only return elements which actually contain both of those attributes.